# sql query to find most repeated word in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL-server called client below like :

```
prediction   |     text 
0                 this is a sample sentence for sample 
1            |    this is a simple sentence this is a simple sentence and important sentence
```

now i need a query that make a column to above table that find 2 words each row and show in third column below like :

```
prediction   |     text                                                              |    top terms
0                 this is a sample sentence for sample sentence                      |    sample,sentence
1            |    important sentence this is a simple sentence and important sentence|    important,sentence
```

please help me to solve it

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Also, I really don't understand what you're asking. Take the time to elaborate on your problem here, as it's unclear. Showing what you've tried as well as telling us why it isn't working will help us help you.

Comment: Parse to separate words, count, enumerate, concatenate back. Specify one DBMS, including precise version.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I use sql server

Comment: I want to specify the most words in each row (2 words per row). For example, my name is Bob, Bob is a computer engineer. In this sentence, if we want to specify the 2 words that have the most repetition, we must select Bob and is

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT prediction, text, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prediction ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
             FROM test
             CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(test.text, ' ')
             GROUP BY prediction, text, value)
SELECT prediction, text, STRING_AGG(value, ', ') most_often_words
FROM cte
WHERE rn < 3
GROUP BY prediction, text;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b195c8eb63143981c56c6b1eb01111be)

Comment: thanks for your reply, the result is as i as expected but i can't use from cross apply, please give me a simple query

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `apply` like this:

```
select t.*, s.words
from t cross apply
     (select concat_ws(',', max(case when seqnum = 1 then s.value end), max(case when seqnum = 2 then s.value end)) as words
      from (select s.value, count(*) as cnt, row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
            from string_split(t.text, ' ') s
            group by s.value
           ) s
      where seqnum <= 2
     ) s;
```

This has some similarities to Akina's solution, but it has one key advantage. It should have better performance.  It avoids the outer aggregation, doing the calculation separately for each row -- which has much smaller amounts of data.

In addition, not aggregating overall makes it trivial to add more columns from the original table.

Comment: thanks for your reply, Can you give a sample without cross apply

Comment: @merchantappsep . . . Why?  This is the most efficient way to do what you want.

Comment: because I have to execute my query in a third party application, and it only support simple sql syntax

Comment: @merchantappsep . . . (1) That doesn't make sense.  This is standard SQL Server syntax.  (2) How would I know if anything else I suggested met the needs of your intermediate layer.  I might suggest that you pass "raw" queries going around the application.

Comment: is it possible show me how to implement it with inner join instead of cross apply?

Comment: @merchantappsep . . . Can't be done.  The alternative is a recursive CTE.

Comment: Is it possible to make it in 2 query and then join them together?